# Swagger-YAML Bad Mapping entry in my products

Tags: api, yaml, swagger

Hi guys I am having difficulties with YAML and I need your help.
I am having this code and it gives me error, and i cant find where or what i am doing wrong.Error msg that i am receiving is below

```
 /product/{productid}/fabric/{fabricid}:
get:
  tags:
  - "Product"
  summary: "Get Fabric by Id"
  description: "This endpoint displays Fabric details"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - name: "fabricid"
    in: "path"
    description: "This is unique identifier of the fabric"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "successful operation"
      schema:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/fabric"
    400:
      description: "Invalid status value"
delete:
  tags:
  - "Product"
  summary: "Delete Fabric by Id"
  description: "Delete Fabric by id"
  operationId: "deleteFabric"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - name: "fabricid"
    in: "path"
    description: "ID of the Fabric that needs to be deleted"
    required: true
    type: "integer"
    minimum: 1.0
    format: "int64"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "successful operation"
      schema:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/fabric"
    400:
      description: "Invalid ID supplied"
    404:
      description: "Fabric not found"
```

Error msg that i am receiving. :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is rather self-explanatory. You defined a path with 2 path parameters:

```
/product/{productid}/fabric/{fabricid}:
```

but you did not define the `productid` parameter in the `parameters` section.

Check out [Paths and Operations](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/paths-and-operations/) and [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/) to learn more about OpenAPI syntax for paths and parameters.

Comment: I checked the documentation and fixed the first error but when i get to the second i am lost.

Comment: Should i give it another name?

Comment: nvm I fixed it all i needed to do is add another parameter :) Thanks Helen you rock <3