# Swagger-YAML Bad Mapping entry in my oppproduct

Tags: api, yaml, swagger

I am having a problem with the path. The error that i am getting is the following check image below. I tried with the link that was pointed out by a community member @Helen [Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEdSb.png) and no luck. Please help me out.
Thanks,
Darko

```
  /opportunity/{opportunityid}/oppproduct/{oppproductid}:
get:
  tags:
  - "Opportunity"
  summary: "Get opp product id for certain opportunity"
  description: "This endpoint displays opp product details"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - name: "opportunityid"
    in: "path"
    description: "This is unique identifier of specific opportunity"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  - name: "oppproductid"
    in: "path"
    description: "This is unique identifier of specific opp product in specific opportunity "
    required: true
    type: "string"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "successful operation"
      schema:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/opportunity"
    400:
      description: "Invalid status value"
put:
  tags:
  - "Opportunity"
  summary: "Update opportunity product from specific opportunity"
  description: "Update this opportunity product."
  operationId: "updateOppProduct"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - name: "opportunityid"
    in: "path"
    description: "Opportunity product with id that need to be updated"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  responses:
    400:
      description: "Invalid Opportunity product supplied"
    404:
      description: "Opportunity product not found"
```

error that i am getting.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) "Duplicated mapping key" error indicates you have duplicate keys in one of the parameters, specifically two `name` keys. You only need one `name`:

```yaml
      parameters:
      - name: "opportunityid"  # <---------
        in: "path"
        description: "Opportunity product with id that need to be updated"
        required: true
        type: "string"
        name: "oppproductid"  # <---------
```

2) The other error is caused by the `schema` keyword in a path parameter:

```yaml
  - in: "path"
    description: "Updated Opp product object"
    type: "string"   # <--- This is the correct way to specify the param type in OAS 2.0
    required: true
    schema:    # <--------- Remove this
        type: integer
```

You don't need `schema` here. In OpenAPI 2.0, path, query and header parameters use `type` directly without the `schema` keyword.

Comment: Hi @Helen if i remove this i am getting additional error. Check the update.

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski the new error is the same as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51487027/113116). Can you figure out from there?